# Is There a Way to See Code Inside DnD Actions in Gamemaker Studio?

Tags: game-maker

I'd like to see the script inside the Drag & Drop actions in Gamemaker Studio. I figure it would be one of the easiest ways to learn GML, and generally a great reference, but I haven't come across any mentions of how to do that; is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](http://yellowafterlife.itch.io/gmvisualizer) service.

Open your object, press `Show Information` and copy all text to the clipboard.
Then paste the data into the first text area (`Paste 'Object Information' code here`) and press `GML` button.